# How can I route the shower plumbing back into the wall?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have purchased an exposed shower valve similar to [this](http://www.plumbworld.co.uk/triton-elina-concentric-tmv2-1738-22868?utm_source=GoogleBase&utm_medium=GB&utm_campaign=GoogleBase&gclid=Cj0KEQjw4qqrBRDE2K_z7Pbvjo8BEiQA39AImcGxQA0EgNbjSlFzwXCAG5EPR8X_h5wD1RPHtX9d288aArIa8P8HAQ#tab-tech) for a ground-floor shower room in my home.

[image]

I would like this connected to a ceiling mounted rainfall shower like [this](http://www.victorianplumbing.co.uk/Premier-Round-Ceiling-Mounted-Shower-Arm-Stainless-Steel-Round-Fixed-Head-ARM21-STY064.aspx?campaign=googlebase&gclid=Cj0KEQjw4qqrBRDE2K_z7Pbvjo8BEiQA39AImWx_llJS4EX20lj5XQpC2JlOw-A7TXQjuZSwrdjn4M4aAvNd8P8HAQ).

[image]

So I need to be able to route the shower valve outlet back into the wall that the valve is fixed to (and then the pipe will go up behind the wall, into the first-floor floor cavity and then back down through the ground-floor ceiling.

But I am not sure what connector to use to attach to the shower valve outlet to route it back through the wall. Any advice?

I have found [this](https://www.ukbathroomstore.co.uk/sagittarius-deluxe-female-shower-return-elbow-chrome-sh589c) but I'm not sure if this is what I need.

[image]

Comment: Just an idea: Perhaps you could run an exposed pipe straight up into the ceiling rather than going through the wall

Comment: Not an option I'm afraid. The pipe must be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is the product that I needed. I connect one end to the shower valve outlet. The long end goes through the wall. On the other side of the wall (in the storage room) I connect it to a pipe going up the wall, into the first-floor floor cavity and then back down through the shower room ceiling. Then I simply connect my rainfall shower there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That type of control valve is intended for the pipe to stay inside the shower enclosure.  Why not just run it up the wall to an elbow and then across the ceiling to another elbow for the showerhead?

Otherwise you would need a control intended for all the plumbing to be inside the wall like [this](http://www.nationalbuildersupply.com/toto-tsptm-brass/p211518):

[image]

There are a number of accessory finishes for the handle and trim.

Comment: I'm limited to an exposed shower valve because the wall is a solid brick wall. And I haven't been able to find a valve whose outlet goes back directly into the wall. I should also mention that on the other side of the wall is a small storage room, so I don't care if pipes are visible there. I would like the pipe up to the shower head to be hidden, hence my requirement to feed the outlet back into the wall. It would then go up the wall in the storage room. I hope this is clear.

Comment: @Submits - The suggestion in this answer is the best one. Run the shower head feed pipe inside the shower. It totally fits with the motif of the control valve. Submit to the solution :^)

Comment: The Mrs insists she doesn't want to see the shower head feed pipe! If you're suggesting there is no alternative option, then that's different. But I would be very surprised if there really was no way for me to feed the outlet back into the wall with some sort of elbow connector.

Comment: @Submits:  I don't understand how it is okay to run the pipe through the wall without not being able to put the valve inside the wall.  What kind of "solid brick wall" allows one but not the other?

Comment: Hi wallyk, the answer to your question is in my first comment to your proposed answer. I would like to run the pipe in the storage room that is on the other side of the wall. I.e. I don't want to run the wall up INSIDE the wall, I just want to run it THROUGH the wall then UP the wall in the storage room.

Comment: Oh!  So you plan to bore through the brick to put a pipe all the way through it.  I guess I understand now.

Comment: Yes. Thankfully, I have found the product I needed. You just need to be able to know what to search for in Google!